# How to use selectize with multiple options with order kept

Tags: php, selectize.js

Using selectize function described under "Tagging" should be able to solve what

```
<select>
```

struggles with - keeping order of selected tags, and yet present keywords TO ADD in AZ order.

However, at http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ I can't find where how i present the possible keywords (apart from the selected). There seems to be only the value-attribute??

Example of application:

At the supermarket: [Yellow] [Fruit] [Fresh] [Organic]

Search will be performed with yellow as highest priority. Order of keywords should be kept. (server-roundtrip)

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do, also does php is related here?

Comment: think example at link provided. How do you provide 100 available tags with only two selected, at the "Tagging" example? (And IF the the textbox is warped to a selectbox on the fly then PHP is involved.)